# PostgreSql INSERT is trying to use existing primary keys

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, cascade, insert-into

I'm experiencing a peculiar problem with a Postgres table. When I try to perform a simple `INSERT`, it returns an error - `duplicate key value violates unique constraint`.

For starters, here's the schema for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE app.guardians
(
  guardian_id serial NOT NULL,
  first_name character varying NOT NULL,
  middle_name character varying,
  last_name character varying NOT NULL,
  id_number character varying NOT NULL,
  telephone character varying,
  email character varying,
  creation_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  created_by integer,
  active boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  occupation character varying,
  address character varying,
  marital_status character varying,
  modified_date timestamp without time zone,
  modified_by integer,
  CONSTRAINT "PK_guardian_id" PRIMARY KEY (guardian_id ),
  CONSTRAINT "U_id_number" UNIQUE (id_number )
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE app.guardians
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The table has 400 rows. Now suppose I try to perform this simple `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO app.guardians(first_name, last_name, id_number) VALUES('This', 'Fails', '123456');
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_guardian_id"
DETAIL:  Key (guardian_id)=(2) already exists.
```

If I try running the same query again, the detail on the error message will be:

```
DETAIL:  Key (guardian_id)=(3) already exists.
```

And

```
DETAIL:  Key (guardian_id)=(4) already exists.
```

Incrementally until it gets to a non-existing `guardian_id`.

What could have gone wrong on this particular table and how is it rectified? I reckon it might have to do with the fact that the table had earlier been dropped using `cascade` and data re-entered afresh but I'm not sure on this theory.

Comment: Try to restart your sequence
```alter sequence "PK_guardian_id" start with (select max(quardian_id) + 1 from app.guardians)```

Comment: Thanks. This actually worked for me. You could post it as an answer so I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I'm glad that the comment was helpful :) and I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of this error is that you have incorrect sequence next_val. It happens when you insert field with auto increment manually

So, you have to alter your sequence next_val

```
alter sequence "PK_guardian_id"
start with (
   select max(quardian_id) + 1 
   from app.guardians
)
```

Note:

> To avoid blocking of concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, ALTER SEQUENCE's effects on the sequence generation parameters are never rolled back; those changes take effect immediately and are not reversible. However, the OWNED BY, OWNER TO, RENAME TO, and SET SCHEMA clauses cause ordinary catalog updates that can be rolled back.
>
> ALTER SEQUENCE will not immediately affect nextval results in backends, other than the current one, that have preallocated (cached) sequence values. They will use up all cached values prior to noticing the changed sequence generation parameters. The current backend will be affected immediately.

Documentation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: Hi! I am having a similar problem, but when I try to run this query, I got `ERROR:  "PK_guardian_id" is not a sequence`. I looked at the table info and found the id column default says `nextval('guardian_id_seq'::regclass)`, so I changed the query to be `alter sequence "guardian_id_seq" start with (select max(quardian_id) + 1 from app.guardians)`. It shows me that the sequence update was successful. But then when I try to insert again, the same error happened...

Comment: as default Postgres uses public schema to find a table. In your case sequence is placed in app schema, so you have table placed in app schema, so yes you have to manually write a schema